# Outlook REST API. How to start new thread on forward message?

Tags: outlook-restapi, outlook-api

First i want to ask how the Outlook client decides if a message that the user wrote should be in the same thread(conversation) or in a new one on forward of a message.

From my observations it checks the subject, but does it check also something else.
I'm using the Outlook rest api v2 and beta versions.
To force the api to create the message in new thread i tried setting the subject in the following patern:

Fwd: { subject of the message i forward} or
Fwr: { subject of the message i forward}

The only successful approach was to add some character to the end of the subject text, but i'm afraid that this might be considered as a bug from some users.

So is there some way to create the message in a new thread when calling /messages/{message_id}/createforward endpoint?

Looking forward for an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different approach when it came to Forward/Reply messages, because I had some issues with Attachments. It seems that my approach could be useful in your case as well.

When I want to forward a message, I retrieve all the attachments of the message and I add 'FW:' at the beginning of the subject, and then I use https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail as If I am sending a new email! That will start a new thread! I hope it works for you.